# Deleting multiple elements in an array one after another in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to delete elements of array using splice of incoming index.

```
handleClick(index) {
    const array = ['el1', 'el2', 'el3', 'el4'];   
    array.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({ data: array });          
}
```

It works just fine but the result is that every time I fire handleClick in order to delete multiple elements I'm starting from the same point of const array. What I need to do is somehow save the array first without one element and when another handleClick is fired it'll work on smaller array, i.e. containing only three elements and making only 2 elements etc. How can I achieve that? Thank you

Comment: Store the array in state not in a variable inside the click handler. Then you only have one instance of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep your `data` array in the component state, and in your `handleClick` method use `setState` with a new array that is a copy of `data` that has had the element with index `index` removed.

You could get your data from the backend in `componentDidMount` and put it in state when the request is complete.

**Example**

```js
function getData() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(["el1", "el2", "el3", "el4"]);
    }, 1000);
  });
}

class App extends React.Component {
  state = { data: [] };

  componentDidMount() {
    getData().then(data => {
      this.setState({ data });
    });
  }

  handleClick(index) {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      const data = [...prevState.data];

      data.splice(index, 1);

      return { data };
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.data.map((el, index) => (
          <button key={el} onClick={() => this.handleClick(index)}>
            {el}
          </button>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention that my array comes from a backend server so it cannot be yet used inside the constructor lifecycle. Sorry for that...